# Print Function without javascript

Tags: html

I am writing an HTML Email Code.
One of the components in the Email Page is the Print Button.
But, As we know the Email Clients blocks the javascript and hence I cannot use window.print();
I read through lots of posts to understand that javascript can nowhere be made to work in email clients??

Is there an alternative that I could use like simulating Ctrl+P without using Javascript??

Comment: @Adriani6 it is not duplicate. Read the question again and also Quentin's answer.

Comment: Also consider that browser-based email clients generally display the email inside their own interface with menus, buttons etc around it, so relying on a basic window.print() isn't good. Press ctrl+p in gmail and it looks awful.

Comment: @VicJordan "... since email clients don't generally support javascript. You can have a button/text link to an external page that is a copy of the email and change the <body> tag to this" Looks exactly like what OP is asking.

Comment: In worst case if you need to let them download pdf file, you can make it and include as attachment and send with message....

Answer (score 2):

The sender of an email cannot do anything to make the recipient's computer print it.

If the recipient wants to print it, then their email client will supply user interface that will allow them to.